# MPI_File_open: Can it be made to give up if it finds a file in use?

Tags: file, io, mpi

I have a situation in an MPI code where many processes will be reading many files and constructing their own domains by getting various pieces of data from various files.  Most files will be read by several processes.  Most processes will read from several files.  I am trying to figure out a way to keep all processes active.  I thought that I might try to write code so that each process will cycle through its list of files (determined at run time, impossible to determine before), try to open with `MPI_File_open`, then, if it sees its current file already in use, go on and try the next file.  This cycle would continue until all data is read.

But is it possible to make `MPI_File_open` behave in this way?  As far as I can tell, if `MPI_File_open` sees a file already in use, it just waits until it can open it.  I haven't been able to find anything that changes this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can pass info to `mpi_file_open` to specify how long to wait before moving on to a new file. This seems to be implementation dependant but from openmpi [docs](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_File_open.3.php) is seems the hint `shared_file_timeout` specifies how long to wait if the file is locked before returning `MPI_ERR_TIMEDOUT`. Something like this could work (I've only tested this compiles/runs correctly when the file is not locked).

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/file.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    MPI_Fint handleA, handleB;
    int rc, ec, rank;
    MPI_File fh;
    MPI_Info info;

    //int fd = open("temp", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    //int result = flock(fd, LOCK_EX);

    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );
    MPI_Errhandler_set(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERRORS_RETURN);
    MPI_Info_create( &info );
    MPI_Info_set(info, "shared_file_timeout", "10.0");
    ec = MPI_File_open( MPI_COMM_WORLD, "temp", MPI_MODE_RDONLY, info, &fh );
    if (ec != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        char estring[MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING];
        int len;
        MPI_Error_string(ec, error_string, &len);
        fprintf(stderr, "%3d: %s\n", rank, error_string);
    } else{
        fprintf(stderr, "%3d: %s\n", rank, "Success");
    }
    MPI_File_close( &fh );
    MPI_Errhandler_set(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Few notes, you probably need to set `MPI_Errhandler` to ensure the `MPI_ERR_TIMEDOUT` error doesn't result in termination. Not sure how to make this portable over different versions of mpi but the [standard](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node315.htm#Node316) does not seem to specify useful hints for this case, leaving it to implementers. For `mpich` this does not work and just blocks endlessly (I can't see an option in mpich to timeout). Non-blocking file open is being considered in the [advanced features of MPI-3](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~balaji/permalinks/2014-06-06-argonne-mpi-advanced.pptx) so probably not soon.

The other alternative is to simply check if the file is locked in whatever language you are using and then open with mpi only if it's not locked.

Comment: So at last I have an inkling of what MPI_Info is about.  Thanks for the answer!